# Any way to know if there's a scheduled shutdown?

Tags: c#, shutdown

I'm currently making a program to schedule computer shutdowns or reboots. You input hours, minutes and seconds and then the computer shuts down/restarts after that given time. A red text then pops-up telling the remaining time before it shuts down. However, if I close the program and reopen it, the shutdown is still scheduled and I'd like to show the remaining time and inform the user.
Is there any way to check if a scheduled shutdown is running ? I'll later make my program write to a log file each shutdown date and duration so I can get the remaining time before it stops.
This is how I stop the computer:

```
Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "/s /f /t " + seconds);
```

Comment: This type of program would be better suited as a service (with a seperate GUI application to configure). Seems like you're re-inventing windows scheduled tasks but there are already libraries available you could use.

Comment: My program is for education purposes/learning while still remaining useful for me. Here's how it looks : https://puu.sh/u76s3/ae4a889fcf.png. I would like to do it from scratch without any other help

Comment: Look for a "shutdown.exe" process?

Comment: You can make a timer in your program, and if time is out - execute 'shutdown.exe "/s /f /t 0'.

Comment: I can but it means that I have to let the program running the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

You could abort the shutdown with: `shutdown.exe /a`

If no shutdown was planned it returns:

`Unable to abort the system shutdown because no shutdown was in progress.(1116)`